# My event trigger is not working and I don't know what is effecting it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

What im trying to do is make ActiveFrame

```
public int activeFrame;
```

Update every time a Click on a new ItemFrame.

[image]

I Have my ActiveFrame linked to a int

```
    public void Awake()
{
    im = GameObject.Find("FrameList").GetComponent<InventoryMenu>();
}

    public void ActivateFrame()
{
     im.activeFrame = index;
     //im.PreviewNewItem(item.ModelPath);
}
```

And I Have it attached to a EventTrigger

[image]

But everytime i Click on  the "ItemFrame" it doesn't work and activeFrame just stays at 0 (Each ItemFrame index is not zero)

Heres the Draw Method

```
void DrawItem(Item it)
{
    tmp = GameObject.Instantiate(ItemFrame);
    tmp.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
    tmpRT = tmp.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    tmpRT.localScale = ItemFrameRT.localScale;
    tmpRT.anchoredPosition = ItemFrameRT.anchoredPosition;
    tmpRT.anchoredPosition += new Vector2(0, ItemFrameRT.rect.height + 1.5f) * -RectSize;
    tmpIf = tmp.GetComponent<ItemFrameScript>();
    tmpIf.index = itemframes.Count;
    itemframes.Add(tmpIf);
    tmpIf.SetValues(it);
    RectSize++;
}
```

Comment: Step through with a debugger, it's much easier to pinpoint the problem that way. There are just too many things that we don't know. Is ActivateFrame  actually called? Is index really not zero? Is something setting activeFrame to zero after ActivateFrame is called? Are you sure you only have one FrameList in scene? Do you have an active EventSystem?

Comment: @defaultUsernameN Each ItemFrame has their own Index from 0 and adding 1. the activeFrame is getting called from on PointerDown as you can see. activeFrame is only getting set to 0 from the start. There is only one FrameList and yes i do have a active EventSystem

Comment: That's why I am suggesting you use a debugger. If all of your assumptions about your code were true, it would work as you expect; something is not working as expected, so evidently one of the things you say does not actually work the way you think. How do you know, for example, that ActivateFrame is called from OnPointerDown and only from OnPointerDown? Did you log it or see it with a debugger?  If so, please include it in the question. It might not get called because it doesn't have a raycast target or something. Than again, how do you know activeFrame is only set to zero once? Debugger? Log?

Comment: Also, I can see ItemFrames are clones - where are you setting their index in code so that it is not zero? Show that part, too, please.

Comment: there i just put the draw method i use for the ui to work. the index is 0 and adding 1 from each itemfame (tmpIf.index = itemframes.Count)

Comment: Okay, that rules out the index part (unless SetValues(it) resets it to 0 again), but not all the others. Can you confirm that ActivateFrame gets called? If you don't know how to use a debugger to do that, you can just add Debug.Log($"Activate frame called on item {index}"); to ActivateFrame method and see if it appears in the console when you click the item. If not, your problem is somewhere around the EventTrigger.

Comment: Yeah when i start it up and click on the items nothing shows up in the console

Comment: Okay, then your EventTrigger doesn't work; I can't really tell you why without seeing the scene, but I would suggest just googling either "eventtrigger usage example" or "eventtrigger doesn't work" and going through a list of things it needs to work (working EventSystem; Canvas as parent; no objects blocking the raycast; able to receive raycasts (raycast target is checked); etc...)

Comment: @defaultUsernameN i Solved it and it was a Raycast target problem Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved It!

All I did was turn off the Raycast Target On The Child Text

(Can't Approve This Until 2 Days)

[image]

Comment: If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: Click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue.